# Single SVG with two animations, one delayed to play after the other via CSS only?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to apply two animations to a single SVG, which I have been able to achieve, however I cannot figure out how to delay one and not the other, as I'd like them to play one and then the other.

I'd like for the first animation (the SVG's path "draws" itself) to play and complete itself, and then for the second animation (The SVG's "fill" fades in) to play afterward.

I have seen people using animation delay in their css, however this would apply to both animations rather than a singular one, as it is a singular SVG target.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/-Infamous/pen/vZmPVe).

And the relevant CSS:

```
.preload-container__svg-wrap svg{
  stroke: #EE2D24;
  fill: #EE2D24;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  stroke-dasharray: 1300;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1300;
  animation: draw/*,fill*/ 5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

@keyframes fill {
  to {fill-opacity: 1}
}
```

The JQ in the pen is not relevant, I am focusing on the CSS issue here.

Comment: Just to be sure, would you like your animations to play one after another, so, draw the logo and then fill it afterwards? Or would you like the logo to be drawn a little, and then the fill action to play in parallel?

Comment: One after another, so draw and then fill. I realise I will have to increase the timing in the JS when it works.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with a queue of selectors that supports this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do like this, where you comma separate the animations.

The `3s` for the `fill` is a delay before it should start its animation

```
animation: draw 5s ease forwards,
           fill 5s ease 3s forwards;
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwwdPO)

*Note, I also changed the script timeout to 6 sec.*

---

*Update*

If to use 1 keyframe, and assuming you want 5 sec. on each animation, increase the duration to 10s and do like this.

Since the `fill-opacity` has a visual delay in its animation, I started it at 35% instead of at 50%.

Note, you need to repeat the `stroke-dashoffset: 0;` at 100%, or else it will disappear in the end of the animation

```
@keyframes drawfill {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1300;
  }
  35% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
.preload-container__svg-wrap svg{
  animation: drawfill 10s ease forwards;
}
```

[Updated codepen 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjjEKx)

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple keyframe selectors into a single animation. More details of this can be found in the link sourced at the end of the answer (and towards the end of the linked page).

With this, you can achieve what I believe you are looking for very easily, by replacing your animations with this (I've also included a revised Codepen with this change below):

```
@keyframes drawAndFill {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: auto;
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

> Assuming you would like to have your fill animation start later, just increase the percentage in the second block, equally if you would like to start it earlier, decrease the percentage.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEEOdv

**Update:**

In response to the comments on the question, and to queue the two stages of the animation seamlessly, the above can be altered as follows to achieve the desired behaviour:

```
@keyframes drawAndFill {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: auto; 
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

---

- @keyframes: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Comment: I tried something similar to this, but couldn't get it working. This workder perfectly though, thank you! =)